# Drools log file

Tags: drools

I have tried and unable to find a document that describes the attributes in Drools log file. For example, in below HelloWorld example log what is type?

```
<org.drools.audit.event.ActivationLogEvent>
  <type>4</type>
  <activationId>Hello World [1]</activationId>
  <rule>Hello World</rule>
  <declarations>m=com.sample.DroolsTest$Message@19a01f9(1)</declarations>
</org.drools.audit.event.ActivationLogEvent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ActivationLogEvent.java:

@param type The type of event.  This can only be ACTIVATION_CREATED, ACTIVATION_CANCELLED, BEFORE_ACTIVATION_FIRE or AFTER_ACTIVATION_FIRE.

From LogEvent.java:

```
public static final int ACTIVATION_CREATED                  = 4;
public static final int ACTIVATION_CANCELLED                = 5;
public static final int BEFORE_ACTIVATION_FIRE              = 6;
public static final int AFTER_ACTIVATION_FIRE               = 7;
```

So I guess your event is an ACTIVATION_CREATED event.

Comment: Thanks. This answered what I am looking for, but I wonder why this is not in a document. Drools is not easy to setup & learn for a beginner!